# Django models to hold a list of objects from another Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a shopping cart for an e-commerce platform. I have made a `Products` model and the I need to create a `Cart` model. One cart can have multiple products in it. I need to create a field `products` in the cart which is a list of multiple product objects. I am not sure how to do it but I can think of two ways:-

1. Create a list of ids of all the products
2. Create a list which contains the product objects inside of them (this might save lookup time)

The product model looks like this:-

```py
class Product(models.Model):

    # Define the fields of the product model
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='market/static/images/products')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)    # Foriegn key with Category Model
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

The `foreignkey` relation doesn't seem to work here because it only stores one entry at a time. I think [ManytoManyFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) might work but I am not able to connect it between these two models.

Comment: yes m2m field is the way. Look at [the example on the same page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields) and replace the names  Person-Group-Membership with User-Product-Basket and you're basically done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `ManyToManyField` is the way to go, you can work with:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Product',
        related_name='carts'
    )

class Product(models.Model):
    # …
```

The Django documentation has a section on [*many-to-many* relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) that specifies how to add, remove, query, etc. `ManyToManyField`s.

Comment: This works perfectly! An error comes if I try to create an  AdminClass while registering the model - `<class 'market.admin.AdminCart'>: (admin.E109) The value of 'list_display[1]' must not be a ManyToManyField.` but it's not a big deal so I just removed it. Thanks!

Comment: I had a follow-up question to this. Suppose, I want to add a field called `quantities` where I want to store an array that contains the quantity of each product that the user adds in the cart so like `products = [1, 2, 3]` and `quantities = [20, 30, 40]`. What field should I build for that? Could you refer me to a link if something like this has been answered? Thanks!

Comment: @PrakharRathi: then you work with a `throug=...` model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through